# Triangle formed by the midpoint and projection of the ends of any chord onto the base of a semicircle does not change shape

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

A chord of constant length slides around in a  semicircle.  The midpoint of the chord and the projections of its ends upon the base form the vertices of a  triangle. Prove that the triangle is isosceles and never changes its shape.

I am trying to understand a proof to this as follows(for brevity I have omitted the proof of isosceles),

Let AB denote the base of the semicircle, let $XY$ be the chord, $M$ the midpoint of $XY$, $C$ and  $D$ the projections of $X$ and $Y$ on $AB$. Let the projection of $M$ onto $AB$ be denoted by $N$. It suffices to show that $∠MCD$ remains unchanged, or equiva­lently, that $∠XCM$ is constant, for all positions of $XY$. To see that this is the case, extend $XC$ to cut the completed circle at $Z$. Then $CM$ is parallel to $ZY$ ($C$ and $M$ are the midpoints of $XZ$ and $XY$, respectively), and consequently $∠XCM=∠XZY$. (*) But $∠XZY$ equals one-half the arc $XY$, and this arc depends only on the length of the chord $XY$. This completes the proof.
[image]

For me, this makes sense until (*), but the final line seems to draw rapid conclusions. Firstly, the meaning of "$∠XZY$ equals one-half the arc $XY$" as I assume arc means arc length, but $∠XZY$ is an angle. It is not obvious to me that the angle depends only on $XY$. By using the $CM$ and $ZY$ parallel arguemnt, I can see $∠XZY$=$∠XCM$=$90-∠MCD$, but this implies it is constant, so surely it is independent of $XY$?.

If convenient, I think it would be best if an answer could include a more thorough rewrite to the ending of the proof that doesn't skip over details that are not self-evident for a noob at geometry.

Comment: "One-half the arc $XY$" is indeed hard to follow. What they mean here is "one-half $\angle XOY$", where $O$ is the centre of the circle. As Fabien's answer says, this is a well-known result.

Comment: @twentyyears, does "doesn't change its shape" means similar triangle?

Answer (score 1):

There is a common result in geometry known as "the inscribed angle theorem": if $A$ and $B$ denotes two distinct points on a circle whose center is $O$, then for any point $C$ on the circle (and "outside" the smaller arc between $A$ and $B$) the following relation will hold
$$\hat{AOB} = 2\times \hat{ACB}$$
In particular, the value of the angle $\hat{ACB}$ does not depend on the choice of $C$.